# Inverse fourier transform of Hermitian function, getting an imaginary part

Tags: fourier-transform, fourier-series

in the cartoon below 
[image]

It shows that if we take the inverse Fourier transform of a Hermitian function, real part even and imaginary part is odd we should get a purely real function in the time domain.

I tried to replicate this by taking a frequency response I have, zero padding it making it even for the real and odd in the imaginary. Shown below
[image]
Although my ifft in Matlab I still have a significant imaginary component, the real is shown left and imaginary on the right.
[image]
I also wrote my own script for DFT/IDFT and tested it on a sine function to make sure I get the same as Matlab. Maybe I have missed something?

Comment: Are you using the whole input vector, or are you specifying an fft length when calling `fft`? Also, a simple one-sample shift will lead to a sinusoidal modulation after dft; make sure you're using the right ,`fftshift`\`ifftshift`

Comment: Maybe it's a numerical/rounding issue? Note that your imaginary part is 1/100th scale of the real part.

Comment: I solved my issue, I had to be very careful in replicating the signal, i wrote it all on paper so i could visually see everything... Should I close the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A (near) sinusoid in one domain (zoom in off center, and you might see it) can indicate a shift away from symmetry in the other domain.  So your initial imaginary signal may be 1 or 1/2 samples off from exact circular symmetry around element 0 (maybe around element 1 in MatLab or Fortran weird array indexing)

Comment: Yeh thanks, I had to be extra careful, I really do not like how matlab index starts from 1 :(